# Limit DynamoDB query result by KB size and not number of Items

Tags: javascript, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I have a service that allows users to extract attributes from JSON stored in DyanmoDB.

Example.. they can send `thing1` which returns a small field like `ABCDEFG` or they can send `thing2` which returns a massive array of strings from within the JSON. or one of 400 other `thing` requests.

This is in a lambda which is called via API Gateway. both of which have payload limits.

I already know you can limit by the number of items returned and use pagination like this:

```
const params = {
  TableName: 'tableName',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'ID = :_id',
  ScanIndexForward: false,
  Limit: 500,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':_id': anId,
  },
};
```

However, if the user requests a `thing` that is large (KB) a `Limit` of 500 may be over the lambda/gateway limits.

Short of setting the limit low, paginating through the results, and accumulating the size of the each `Item.thing`, until the limit is nearly reached, is there a way do do this through the DynamoDB SDK? I'm inclined to think, no.

Comment: I'm afraid you're correct, there is no way to do this natively in DDB.  Keep in mind that DDB will not return data sets larger than 1MB before paginating results, even if you ask it for more.  In your example of 1KB size items, a request with limit=500 would return half a MB.  That should be well below the lambda and API Gateway payload limits (6MB and 10MB respectively, I believe).

Comment: Correct @SethGeoghegan - that's worthy of an answer, don't you think? ;-)

Comment: @SethGeoghegan Ah, you know... i didn't take that into account. You are correct, the 1MB initial limit will effectively do what I'm trying to do in the code. Thanks for pointing that out! I'm a little ashamed that I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you're correct, there is no way to do this natively in DDB. Keep in mind that DDB will not return data sets larger than 1MB before paginating results, even if you ask it for more. In your example of 1KB size items, a request with limit=500 would return half a MB. That should be well below the lambda and API Gateway payload limits (currently 6MB and 10MB respectively, I believe)